# Flutter: Future<void> should only have one instance running at a time

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, future

I am kinda new to Dart/Flutter and am struggling with the following scenario.
I have a InAppWebView (headless) which automatically shall log-on to a webpage and do some stuff there.
It has to navigate through multiple pages and do different actions based on which page to get to a final result.

My solution right now is, to call a `Future<void>` once the loading process of an url has been done.
This `Future<void>` then checks on which page it is, and starts processing data and will initiate navigation to the next step (url).

However, I am facing the problem that this `Future<void>` at some point is running in multiple instances.
So my question:
Is there a way how to ensure a `Future<void>` can only be running ONE-AT-A-TIME?
E.g. stop the current working `Future<void>` and start a new instance?

Comment: could you share some code?

Comment: I can just write you an example here:

    
onLoadDone:(url, title){
doAction(url,title);
}

Future<void> doAction(String url, String title){
if(url == "examplea"){
do this and this and this
return;
}
elseif(url == exampleb"){
do some other stuff...
return;
}
...

Comment: Make a mutex lock to avoid other future enter? Release lock after future is done.

Comment: Thanks yellowgray! Your suggestion might just be what I need. For now it is working as expected! How can I flag your answer as the solution?